# Programmatically Adding holidays Calendars using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'd like to know if it is possible to programmaticaly add Holidays Calendars using Exchange Web services ?

When using Outlook client, you can select holidays calendars from any countries to appear in your own calendar.

What I would liek to do is allowing user to select countries in my app, then checking if its personnal calendar contains the selected holidays calendars and if I can't find one, add it programmaticaly (the user is authenticated using Exchange Web Service Managed API)...

(My app is developped in C#)

any help welcome,

Fred.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. A "holiday" calendar entry is no different than any other appointment, so to add a holiday appointment, you'd search the user's appointments for each holiday date to determine if a "holiday" appointment already exists, and add a new appointment, if necessary.

As long as your app is the only thing adding holiday appointments, it should be easy to determine if an appointment exists, as you can use a naming convention or add a user property to indicate it's a "holiday" appointment.

There's always a risk that you'd miss an existing holiday appointment and add a second appointment---you'll need to determine how big of a risk this is.

Comment: unfortunatly, my app won't be the only one thing changing calendars subscriptions :( Actually, you can select as many holiday calendars as you need through Outlook (one calendar per country). What I would like to do is checking if the current logged in user has subscribed to my default country holiday calendar, and if not, make the subscription in his name (as the user is authenticated through my app)...

Comment: The final objective is of course getting holiday calendar for a specified country using Exchange... (this is the only way I have found to resolve this, unless it is possible to access directly to Exchange holiday calendars using the managed API !?)